# JQuery only works on scroll and not on page refresh

Tags: jquery

My code below only works when I scroll down to trigger the conditions in the "if" statement. But when I don't scroll back up and instead refresh the page to see the effect again - it doesn't work. I need the code to also work every time I refresh the page, not just on page scroll. Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
      $(".main-pic-bg").fadeIn("slow");
      $(".main-pic-bg").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
      $(".main-pic-bg").hide("slow");
      $(".main-pic-bg").hide("slow");
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 650) {
      $(".fullscreen-bg-video").hide();
      $(".main-pic-bg-title").addClass("load2");
      $(".main-pic-bg-content1").addClass("load2");
    } else {
      $(".fullscreen-bg-video").show("slow");
      $(".main-pic-bg-title").removeClass("load2");
      $(".main-pic-bg-content1").removeClass("load2");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean every time the user refreshes the page or scrolls the page it executes that code, then its better that you add that code into a function, just for the sake of not repeating code two times:

```
function update() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
        $(".main-pic-bg").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".main-pic-bg").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        $(".main-pic-bg").hide("slow");
        $(".main-pic-bg").hide("slow");
    }

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 650) {
        $(".fullscreen-bg-video").hide();
        $(".main-pic-bg-title").addClass("load2");
        $(".main-pic-bg-content1").addClass("load2");
    } else {
        $(".fullscreen-bg-video").show("slow");
        $(".main-pic-bg-title").removeClass("load2");
        $(".main-pic-bg-content1").removeClass("load2");
    }
}
```

Then place the events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    update();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    update();
});
```

If you noticed, the scroll event is not inside the ready event, thats because if it was, then it would only update if you scroll after the page was ready. Now that it is separated it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code solved my problem and your explanation enlightened me!

Answer (score 2):

Try refactor your code like this:

```
  $(window).on( 'scroll load', function(){

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
      $(".main-pic-bg").fadeIn("slow");
      $(".main-pic-bg").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
      $(".main-pic-bg").hide("slow");
      $(".main-pic-bg").hide("slow");
    }

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 650) {
      $(".fullscreen-bg-video").hide();
      $(".main-pic-bg-title").addClass("load2");
      $(".main-pic-bg-content1").addClass("load2");
    } else {
      $(".fullscreen-bg-video").show("slow");
      $(".main-pic-bg-title").removeClass("load2");
      $(".main-pic-bg-content1").removeClass("load2");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried your code and it worked fine.